# MyOrder in Express.js

Tags: express

How to create order model and ordersRoute in express.js ?

```
var globalConfig     = require('../../public/js/globalConfig'),
    _                = require('underscore'),
    mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');

module.exports = function(mongoose) {
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
        deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);
    var OrderSchema = new Schema({
        code             : String,
        date             : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        status           : { type: String, enum: _.keys(globalConfig.orderStatus)},
        _products        : [{
            //product      : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'},
            product      : {},
            quantity     : Number
        }],
        user             : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
        totalOrder       : Number,
        _addresses       : {
            billing      : {
                name     : String,
                address  : String,
                zipCode  : String,
                city     : String,
                country  : String
            },
        // Times
        createdAt        : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        updatedAt        : { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    });
    OrderSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
    OrderSchema.plugin(deepPopulate, {});
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', OrderSchema);
}
```